# Return all keys with the same value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file, in this case called alarm.file.  The below code goes through each line of the file and if the contains "Blade_HostName" it adds it to a list and assigns a stripped version of the line to a variable, then it checks for "Node:" in the file and adds the Blade_HostName as a key in a dictionary and adds the "Node:" as the key's value.

I'm stuck at the next step. I want it to go through the dictionary and return all the keys that share the same value. I can handle it from there.

From the returned list of keys, I will use subprocess to ssh to the value, run a command on all keys with that value, and then do the same for each key with other unique values (as is seen by the commented out code at the bottom).

Thanks in advance.

Sample of the alarm.file in case it's needed:

Alarm Type: Storage restarted Alert
  Node: 10.xx.xx.2
  HostName:
  Summary: E CM_HELLO 7213 Storage 10.xx.xx.1 was restarted
  BladeIP_Storage_Was_restarted = 10.xx.xx.1
  Blade_HostName = r33b26
  Xcat_Info = njxcat01
  Region = NJ
  Acknowledged: 0
  FirstOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:32 EST
  LastOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:32 EST
  Number of Occurrences = 1
 -------------------
  Alarm Type: Storage restarted Alert
  Node: 10.xx.xx.2
  HostName: 
  Summary: E CM_HELLO 7213 Storage 10.xx.xx.2 was restarted
  BladeIP_Storage_Was_restarted = 10.xx.xx.2
  Blade_HostName = r39b14
  Xcat_Info = njxcat01
  Region = NJ
  Acknowledged: 0
  FirstOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:40 EST
  LastOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:40 EST
  Number of Occurrences = 1
 -------------------
  Alarm Type: Storage restarted Alert
  Node: 10.xx.xx.3
  HostName: 
  Summary: E CM_HELLO 7213 Storage 10.xx.xx.3 was restarted
  BladeIP_Storage_Was_restarted = 10.xx.xx.3 
  Blade_HostName = r54b05
  Xcat_Info = njxcat01
  Region = NJ
  Acknowledged: 0
  FirstOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:43 EST
  LastOccurrence: 02/24/2016 09:49:43 EST
  Number of Occurrences = 1
 -------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, sys, subprocess

myRackDict = {}
myRack = ""
myListX = []
myBladeList = []

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
   print('Not a valid file, please try again')
   sys.exit()
elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
   myFile = sys.argv[1]
   if myFile == '':
       sys.exit()

with open(myFile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Blade_HostName' in line:
            line = line.replace('Blade_HostName = ', '')
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            line = line.lstrip()
            #print(line)
            myRack = line
            #myBladeList.append(myRack)
        elif 'Node: ' in line:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            line = line.lstrip(' ')
            line = line.replace('Node: ', '')
            if not myRack in myRackDict.keys():
                myRackDict[myRack] = line
            else:
                continue

print(myRackDict)
#myString = ('for i in ' + ' '.join(myBladeList) + ' ;do echo $i; psh $i monit summary; done')
#print(myString)

"""
mySsh = subprocess.check_output("ssh " + "root@" + myxCat['hixxcat'] + " 'psh r1046b01 monit summary'", shell=True)
encoded = mySsh.decode()
print(encoded)
"""
```

Comment: You've got another problem. Since Node preceded Blade_HostName, `myRackDict[myRack] = line` is using the old blade from the previous section.

Comment: I hadn't realized that.. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll see if I can fix.

Comment: @tdelaney I see where I screwed that up. Orignally I was using a different field that shows up after Blade_HostName and I changed it to Node.  I'll re-arrange. Thanks again for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with a `defaultdict` so that each value is associated with a list of keys.

```
import collections

val_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in myRackDict.items():
    val_map[v].append(k)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the `dict`:

```
d = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 1}
keys_for_1 = [k for k in d if d[k] == 1]
print(keys_for_1)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'baz']
```