# Python count duplicates over lists in list

Tags: python

I have a list containing several other lists. I would like to count how often one element occurs in all of these lists.
For example:

```
my_list_of_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[],[2,3,5]]
```

the output could be something like:

```
1: 2
2: 3
3: 2
4: 1
5: 1
```

A specific element only occurs ones per single list.

Some piece of code would be very helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. Is it also possible to create an output like this: `1,3: 2` `2:3` `4,5:1` etc. In words: one and three occurred 2 times etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ct = Counter([jtem for item in a for jtem in item])
>>> ct
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

OR

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> ct = Counter(chain.from_iterable(a))
>>> ct
Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

This should help you.

Comment: Thank you! it works great! Do you also have a solution on how to summarize the results further? (see my comment on the question)

Comment: dict(ct) will give you what you want.
If the answer is good enough, could you verify it too. Thanks!

Comment: @SridharMurali There is no need to convert the counter object into dict again, because the Counter class itself is a subclass of dict.

Comment: This leads to the same output than ct just converted to a dictionary.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, I was aware of it but, I thought Lisa wanted the results without "Counter". Seems like i misread what she wanted. Apologies.

Comment: No problem. I would like to "summarize" the keys of the dictionary if they have the same value. Like number 1 and 3 occurred both two times etc.

Comment: ok I found an answer to the second question in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817975/return-all-keys-with-the-same-value-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

using [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Monoids_in_computer_science)

```
from collections import Counter    
Counter(sum(my_list_of_lists, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={}
#l is the given list
for l1 in l:
    #l1 is nested list
    for j in l1:
    #j is element
        if j in d.keys():
             d[j]+=1
        else:
             d[j]=1
```

You have a dict d with elements as keys and value as count of elements.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness you could use numpy for this as well:

```
import numpy as np
my_list_of_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[],[2,3,5]]
np_array_of_arrays = np.concatenate([np.array(i) for i in my_list_of_lists])
d = dict(zip(*np.unique(np_array_of_arrays , return_counts=True)))
print(d)

{1.0: 2, 2.0: 3, 3.0: 2, 4.0: 1, 5.0: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should flatten your `list` of `list`s so it would become, just `list`, you could do it following way:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[],[2,3,5]]
flat = sum(data,[])
```

Now `flat` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5]`, now we can get unique elements:

```
uniq = list(set(flat))
```

Finally we can get number of occurence and store it in `dict`:

```
quantity = {i:flat.count(i) for i in uniq}
```

Which is:

```
print(quantity) #{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

I want to note that every part of this task can be done different way and most importantly I want to show than task might become easier to implement (or finding ready implementations) after it would be divided into sub-tasks.