# How would I isolate specific words containing a specific character?

Tags: python, string

So I'm creating an analytics bot for my EPQ that counts the number of time a specific hashtag is used. How would I go about checking if a word in a string of other words contains a `#`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be good to provide some example inputs and your expected outputs, so people know exactly what you want. It's much more precise than trying to describe it in words. Two or three examples would probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

A first approach can check if a string has a substring using `in`, and gather a count for each unique word using a dictionary:

```py
texts = ["it's friday! #TGIF", "My favorite day! #TGIF"]
counts = {}

for text in texts:
    for word in text.split(" "):
            if "#" not in word:
                    continue
            if word not in counts:
                    counts[word] = 0
            counts[word] += 1

print(counts)
# {'#TGIF': 2}
```

This could be improved further with:

- using `str.casefold()` to normalize text with different casings
- using regex to ignore certain chars, eg '#tgif!' should be parsed as '#tgif'

Answer (score 1):

You already have a decent answer, so it really just comes down to what kind of data you want to end up with. Here's another solution, using Python's [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) on the same data:

```py
import re

texts = ["it's friday! #TGIF #foo", "My favorite day! #TGIF"]

[re.findall('#(\w+)', text) for text in texts]
```

Regex takes some getting used to. The `'#(\w+)'` 'captures' (with the parentheses) the 'word' (`\w+`) after any hash characters (`'#'`). It results in a list of hashtags for each 'document' in the dataset:

```
[['TGIF', 'foo'], ['TGIF']]
```

Then you could get the total counts with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55277593/3381305):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(finds))
```

Yielding this dictionary-like thing:

```
Counter({'TGIF': 2, 'foo': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = " if a word in a string of other words contains a #"
if "#" in test:
    print("yes")
```